# How can I dynamically generate Mongoose discriminators (at runtime?)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**TL;DR: Is there a safe way to dynamically define a mongoose discriminator at runtime?**

I have an app with a MongoDB collection where users have some control over the underlying schema.

I could add one or two fixed, required fields and just use [mongoose.Mixed](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed) for the remainder that users can change, but I'd like to make use of Mongoose's validation and discriminators if I can.

So, what I've got is a second collection `Grid` where the users can define the shape they'd like their data to take, and in my *main* model `Record`, I've added a function to dynamically generate a discriminator from the definition in the second collection.

The code for my `Record` model looks like this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const recordSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fields: {
        type: Array,
        required: true
    }
}, {
    discriminatorKey: "grid"
})

const Record = mongoose.model("Record", recordSchema)

module.exports = grid => {

    // Generate a mongoose-compatible schema from the grid's field definitions
    const schema = grid.fields.map(field => {
        if(field.type === "string") return { [field.name]: String }
        if(field.type === "number") return { [field.name]: Number }
        if(field.type === "checkbox") return { [field.name]: Boolean }
        return { [field.name]: mongoose.Mixed }
    })

    return Record.discriminator(grid._id, new mongoose.Schema(schema))
}
```

This is inside an Express app, and I use the model in my middleware handlers something like this:

```
async (req, res) => {
    const grid = await Grid.findById(req.params.id)
    const Record = await GenerateRecordModel(grid)
    const records = await Record.find({})
    res.json({
        ...grid,
        records
    })
}
```

This works **great** on the first request, but after that I get an error `Discriminator with name “ ” already exists`.

I guess this is because only one discriminator with its name per model can exist.

I could give every discriminator a unique name whenever the function is called:

```
    return Record.discriminator(uuidv4(), new mongoose.Schema(schema), grid._id)
```

But I imagine that this isn't a good idea because discriminators seem to persist beyond the lifetime of the request, so am I laying the groundwork for a memory leak?

I can see two ways forward:

1. **COMPLICATED?** Define all discriminators when the app boots up, rather than just when a HTTP request comes in, and write piles of extra logic to handle the user creating, updating or deleting the definitions over in the `Grid` collection.
2. **SIMPLER?** Abandon using discriminators, just use mongoose.Mixed so anything goes as far as mongoose is concerned, and write any validation myself.

Any ideas?

Comment: seems like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47601766/mongoose-how-to-find-discriminators-already-in-use#47835288) could be relevant, but i'm confused about how to adapt it to my situation?

Comment: Are your users defining classes at runtime? If not, both discriminator field names and values in those fields are fixed sets.

Comment: exactly - the idea is that the user could alter the schema (grids) and add data against it (records) all within the web app, without me needing to reboot it